# How to specify from on the fly in laravel 8 mail::send

Tags: laravel, email

From the contact form on my website, I send an confirmation email to the visitor and an email to the website admin.  Both email are coming to the email address defined in .env.
How can I change the from field for the email sent to admin?
My current code where the second Mail:: gives an error.

```
   // send html email to user
   Mail::to(request('email'))
   ->send(new ContactWebsite($emailFields));
   // send html email to admin
   Mail::to("newemail@address")
   ->from(request('email'))
   ->send(new ContactWebsite($emailFields));
```

Daniel solution is good but how do I implement it in my case?

In the Contact Contoller store function, I put the fromAddress in the $emailFields object:

```
 $emailFields = (object) [
 'fromName' => $fullnameUser,
 'fromEmail' => request('email'),
 'fromAddress' => $fullnameUser.' <'.request('email').'>',
 'subject' => '...',
 'body' => request('body')
 ];
```

Then in the Mailable:

```
public function __construct($emailFields) {
    $this->emailFields = $emailFields;
    $this->fromAddress = $emailAddress['fromAddress'];
}

public function build() {
    return $this->markdown('emails.contact-confirm-user');
}
```

Is the syntax correct in the __construct function?

And how do I pass the $this->fromAddress in the build function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are supposed to define the `->from()` part in your `Mailable` class's `build()` function (in your case `ContactWebsite`) either as part of the `$emailFields`, or as a second parameter. Then you just use it in the `build` function:

```
class ContactWebsite extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    
    private $fromAddress = 'default@value.com';

    public function __construct($emailFields, $fromAddress = null)
    {
        if ($fromAddress) {
            $this->fromAddress = $fromAddress;
        }
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from($this->fromAddress)
            // Whatever you want here
            ->send()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Daniel. In my case I already define the 'fromAddress' in the object $emailFields.  Thus I guess what I should do is remove the ", $fromAddress = null" in the __construct function and replace "$this->fromAddress = $fromAddress;" by "$this->fromAddress = $emailAddress['fromAddress'];" Is that the correct syntax?

Comment: Yes that is correct. If it is already part of `$emailFields` you can use `$this->fromAddress = $emailAddress['fromAddress'];` and then in your `build()` function use `return $this->from($this->fromAddress)->...`

Comment: I am still struggling with this @Daniel.  I think I need more help.  I will rewrite my question below for clarity.